# encoding post information in php and storing it in DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

So i have this problem with storing information in database. I just inserted raw post data and words like "Automātiskā" ( in latvian ) appears like "Autom?tisk?". Then i encoded all my data like this :

```
 $data = array(
'marka' => utf8_encode($this->input->post('marka')), etc
```

( developing with CodeIgniter )

Now "Automātiskā" appears like "AutomÄtiskÄ" and "Benzīns" like :"BenzÄ«ns" etc.

I have tried several other things like adding php header, but no result, just error.

I am confused with all this encoding stuff and would like to learn about easiest way to put my latvian characters in database (what code lines i need to add). All information i search make my mind more mixed up.

ALSO, do i need to set database "Collation" field to something like UTF8_latvian_ci or UTF8_unicode_ci , becouse in default i have latin1_swedish_ci .

ALSO later i will need to display that info in my page. Do i need do some decoding stuff again? Would like to hear about that too.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the proper (utf-8) headers in php, also have your db in utf-8 and you should be fine.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

For your database I recommend: `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: this is for outputing info from db, i guess... will try it later.